# Is it possible to create keyword-based RSS feeds?

Tags: support, feed

I would like to know if it's possible to create custom RSS Feeds with keywords for Stack Overflow.

For instance, I would like to create a feed related to the R package "RQDA," so if someone asks a new question with the word "RQDA" here, I can be informed via my RSS reader.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a tool I wrote, [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source).

**Example:** a feed for all questions containing "RQDA":

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/search?intitle=RQDA

This will return a feed containing a list of all questions containing "RQDA" in the title.

Comment: Looks like it isn't working.  The page you linked to just returns an error.

Comment: @Kibbee: Sorry about that. I've fixed the link now.

Comment: @George Edisson thank you so much for your Stack2RSS tool I enjoy it a lot.

Comment: The link is broken again...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it looks like you can create feeds from tags, which is good enough for me.